# APACHE POI - Setting cell style as time

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to set a column style as Time, to show date objects as HH:mm

I tried this method:

```
private static void setTimeColumnFormatAsTime() {

    CellStyle cs = m_workbook.createCellStyle();
    CreationHelper createHelper = m_workbook.getCreationHelper();
    cs.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("HH:mm"));

    m_sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(TIME_COL, cs);
}
```

But all I get is somethink like: 25986.4895833333. When I manually format the cell as  **Time** I get the correct display I need: 11:45

What am I doinfg wrong?

Thank you all.

Comment: What is TIME_COL set to, and what column is it supposed to point at in the sheet? I assume setDefaultColumnStyle uses and index that starts at 0, so depending on what TIME_COL is set to, you might be one column off?

Comment: @johankr TIME_COL=0 and I need to format Column A

Comment: What happens when you apply that cell style to the cells you put the times into?

Comment: @Gagravarr Do you mean I should set a style per cell and not per column?

Comment: Yes, or both. IIRC column styles are only used for new cells added in the Excel UI in certain conditions. Anything else needs explicit cell-level styling to have an effect

Comment: @Gagravarr Setting specifically each cell style did the trick! Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Gagravarr (see the comments above) I manage to set the style to Date in excel.

I now set the style for each cell specifically ,and not as a default for the whole column:

```
private static void setTimeColumnFormatAsTime(Cell a_cell) {

    CellStyle cs = m_workbook.createCellStyle();
    CreationHelper createHelper = m_workbook.getCreationHelper();
    cs.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("HH:mm"));
    a_cell.setCellStyle(cs);
}
```

Comment: Don't do it like this - you'll run out of cell styles. Cell styles are workbook scoped, so create the style once and re-use it

Comment: @Gagravarr So, is that the reason that suddenly, on the 44 cell it didn't format it as a Date???

Comment: Could be, if you ran out of cell styles. Follow the documentation, create the cell styles once, and re-use them